# tern_for_vim (ternjs) returns 403 access denied

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, macvim, tern

Trying to get JavaScript completion working in MacVim, using [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) + [TernJS](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim).

I've followed the install instructions for both plugins (I use Vundle to manage vim plugins), which included running `./install.sh` script inside the YCM plugin folder, and `npm install` inside the TernJS plugin folder. Installation of both appears to have completed successfully.

However I'm not getting any JS completions as I type; and if I try to manually trigger something in TernJS (eg. `:TernDef`), I get a HTML error page back from the local TernJS server, indicating a 403 Access Denied error.

If I launch MacVim with sudo (eg. `sudo mvim`); everything seems to work fine.

Also, without sudo, I can manually post a JSON document to the TernJS server (outside of vim) and get a valid response back.

I'm running MacVim 7.4.71 (installed via Homebrew; compiled with python support ), and node 0.10.21 (also installed via Homebrew).

Any ideas on what I could check, so that I can have TernJS completions without needing to use sudo to launch MacVim?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

My shell profile was setting the `$http_proxy` env variable so the requests from MacVim to the local TernJS server were trying to go out through a proxy server.

Fixed by adding `export no_proxy=localhost` to my shell profile, so that requests to `http://localhost` don't use a proxy.